# Is this the a situation for using a service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background-process

I try to implement a mechanism in my progress which checks in a defined period of time if a collection of SQL statements return a specific value (e.g.:
SQL: `SELECT Count(Columns_A) AS Counted FROM TABLE B`

If the return Value is greater than 1 =>

write Flag into Row =>

next Statement...

So this should be iterated with a loop. And my idea was to build a service with a thread which triggers every x seconds this loop to iterate. It´s for an background job which checks the state of some conditions. I'm not very firm in Android programming so I don`t know if this is the way it should be done, or if there is a smarter way to do it.

P.S. I don't want you to give me the code. I want to do implement it by myself. I just want a hint if the method I correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a job you should be doing in a Service specially when UI does not need to be shown and you need to do this. Also if you need the result of this operation in several Activities... It's much easier for a service to notify N activities then making some sort odlf communication between running and pauses activites.